# Reputation and ability to edit other people’s posts

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I see in the FAQ for SU (and MSU) regarding Reputation:
2000 Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits

I recall that for the first post I edited (another persons Question), my reputation was less than 100.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone, including anonymous users can suggest edits to a post. Their edits will be subjected to peer review and when 2 concurring approvals are accepted, the edit goes through.

With 2000+ rep, you gain the privilege to have your edits affect the post directly, without subjecting it to peer review.

Answer (score 0):

Below 2000 rep, anyone can edit anyone else's posts, however it takes a 2000+ rep user to review and approve or reject the edit.

Once you reach 2000 you are trusted enough to edit without approval.